# Paging result of get_posts in function

Tags: get-posts

I have created a function to use as a shortcode to allow me to display a specific post type on my page.
The function works well, but I would like to the results to be paged, and the navigation only to appear if needed.
her is my current code

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array("country" => '' ), $atts));
$country = preg_replace('~�*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $country );  
$argsq = array ('post_type' => 'quote',
                    'country' => $country,
                'orderby' => 'meta_value' 
              );


$testim= get_posts($argsq );
$output = '';
foreach ($testim as $testim_post){

$output .= "";
$output .= "".$testim_post->post_content."
";
$output .= $testim_post->post_title;
$output .= "";         
}   
return $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

add this pagination function:

```
function pagination( $query, $baseURL = get_bloginfo( $url ), $echo = true ) {  
    $page = $query->query_vars["paged"];  
    if ( !$page ) $page = 1;  
    $qs = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] ? "?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : "";  
    // Only necessary if there's more posts than posts-per-page  
    if ( $query->found_posts > $query->query_vars["posts_per_page"] ) {  
        $re = '<ul class="paging">'; 
        // Previous link? 
        if ( $page > 1 ) { 
            $re .= '<li class="previous"><a href="'.$baseURL.'page/'.($page-1).'/'.$qs.'">« previous</a></li>'; 
        } 
         // Loop through pages 
        for ( $i=1; $i <= $query->max_num_pages; $i++ ) { 
            // Current page or linked page? 
            if ( $i == $page ) { 
                $re .= '<li class="active">'.$i.'</li>'; 
            } else { 
                $re .= '<li><a href="'.$baseURL.'page/'.$i.'/'.$qs.'">'.$i.'</a></li>'; 
            } 
        } 
        // Next link? 
        if ( $page < $query->max_num_pages ) { 
        $re .= '<li><a href="'.$baseURL.'page/'.($page+1).'/'.$qs.'">next »</a></li>'; 
        } 
        $re .= '</ul>';  
        if ($echo){
            echo $re;
        }else{
            return $re;
        }
    }  
}
```

then add the paged parameter to your shortcode query and get the current page permalink:

```
global $post;
$baselink = get_permalink($post->ID);
extract(shortcode_atts(array("country" => '' ), $atts));
$country = preg_replace('~?*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $country ); 
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$argsq = array (
    'post_type' => 'quote',
    'country' => $country,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // you have to specify a meta_key for this to work
    'page' => $page 
);


$testim= get_posts($argsq );
```

and just before you return the pagination with your output:

```
return $output .pagination($testim,$baselink,false);
```

Comment: thx Bainterent, I am not getting the last bit, ie return $output .pagination($testim,$baselink,false); where this should go?

Comment: @salocin: replace your `return $output;` with `return $output .pagination($testim,$baselink,false);` at the end of your shortcode function.